# Onclick function inside a-href tag in angular controller calling method in same controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am loading data from the controller and displaying in view as a list of clickable items in HTML. When selected i want to call a method in the controller to perform some logic.

```
 items.push("<li><a href='#' ng-click='choosePostcode(" + result.postcode + ");return false;'>" + result.postcode + "</a></li>");
```

This displays correctly on the view but when clicked my choosePostcode method is not hit. 
I have tried a few alternatives with no success.

```
'<li><a href="#" ng-click="alert("test");"> click </a></li>'

'<li><a href="#" ng-click="javascript:alert("test");"> click </a></li>'

    "<li><a href='#' onclick="choosePostcode(result.postcode);return false;"> + result.postcode + </a></li>");
```

Latest attempt from comments below. Still no success.

```
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="PropertyController">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input name="s" class="form-control" ng-model="addr" type="text" placeholder="Search..." size="40" />
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Send" ng-click="addr_search()">Search</button>
                                </span>

                            </div>
                            <div id="search">

                                    <ul>
                                        <li ng-repeat="result in results">
                                            <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault();choosePostcode(result.postcode)">{{result.postcode}}</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>                                 
                            </div>
```

Controller Class.js

```
 function MarkerDrop() {
                    $.getJSON('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes?lon=' + $scope.userLongitude + '&lat=' + $scope.userLatitude, function (data) {                         
                        if (data.result !== null) {
                            $scope.results = data.result;
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: why you are construction `html` string? - you should use `ng-repeat` and generate DOM in template. In your case the string you insert is not compiled. So, `ng-click` directive doesn't have any effect. if you could share the result object and piece of logic you trying to achieve I can help u

Comment: @ajaiJothi I'm new to angular. I had it as `onclick` previously but it was no different. The result object is all the data related to a click on a map. Latitude, Longitude, County ... and Postcode. I just want the selected Postcode passed into a method to save it as a global variable in the controller class.       `function choosePostcode(postcode) {                           
                            globalPostcode = postcode;
                        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just assuming the case from your comment. Try something like this,

**Template:**

```
...
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="result in results">
      <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault();choosePostcode(result.postcode)">{{result.postcode}}</a>
   </li>
</ul>
...
```

**Controller**:

```
...
$scope.globalPostcode = '';
$scope.choosePostcode = function(postcode) { 
   $scope.globalPostcode = postcode; 
};
...
function MarkerDrop() {
    $http.get('https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes?lon=' + $scope.userLongitude + '&lat=' + $scope.userLatitude)
    .then(function(result) {                         
       $scope.results = result.data || [];
    });
}
...
```

Comment: I have tried this method and updated my original question. The "results" contains the correct data but I am unsure if anything is passed to the view or not as I cannot debug the HTML. Thanks!

Comment: you are using `$.getJSON` which is a jquery method and it is out of angular scope. So u have to use either `$http` service or use `$scope.$apply()` after updating `$scope.results` - to notify angular that the scope value is changed

Comment: Thank you for the help! Adding in the `$scope.$apply()` sorted it

Answer (score 0):

If you're inserting html that is generated in the javascript, it has to be run through the `$compile` service in order for angular to recognize it.

Check out the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).